# Database Join Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am having a problem with a database join query and I am looking for someone to help me out.

Basically I've got two tables, Invoices and Receipts.

Invoices

```
Invoice ID
Amount
Date_Added
```

Receipts

```
ReceiptID
InvoiceID
Amount
Date_Added
```

The thing is that I need to produce a table like below, but I have multiple records in Receipts and I am pretty sure that the data is stored in a good way, just not exactly sure what the query would be.

```
InvoiceID   RecieptID    Amount     Balance     Date_Added
1           0            100.00     100.00      01.05.2012
1           1            100.00     0.00        02.05.2012
2           0            250.00     250.00      03.05.2012
3           0            100.00     350.00      04.05.2012
2           2            100.00     250.00      05.05.2012
```

Does this make sense? So it should be in date order. So effectively I can see line by line what is going on each date.

Comment: can you post sample data from both tables? And what you have tried?

Comment: Looks like running totals. I assume you don't care who the invoice was sent to, or who the receipt came from? Seems like interesting accounting to say the least. :-)

Comment: Hi, I've tried to do an INNER JOIN on the Date as I thought this might help but it doesn't bring out the invoice. Just the receipts.

Comment: Hi Aaron, I've removed the irrelevant fields obviously ;)

Comment: Recommend you use safe, unambiguous date formats. I can't tell if that is May 1, May 2, May 3... or Jan 5, Feb 5, Mar 5... YYYYMMDD or YYYY-MM-DD are much clearer to users no matter what country they're in or language they speak. Well with a couple of exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setup:

```
USE tempdb;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Invoices
(
  InvoiceID INT,
  Amount DECIMAL(12,2),
  DateAdded SMALLDATETIME
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.Receipts
(
  ReceiptID INT,
  InvoiceID INT,
  Amount DECIMAL(12,2),
  DateAdded SMALLDATETIME
);

SET NOCOUNT ON;

INSERT dbo.Invoices SELECT 1, 100, '20120501'
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 250, '20120503'
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 100, '20120504';

INSERT dbo.Receipts SELECT 1, 1, 100, '20120502'
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 2, 100, '20120505';
```

Query:

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT InvoiceID, ReceiptID, Amount, DateAdded, 
   rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DateAdded)
  FROM
  (
    SELECT InvoiceID, ReceiptID = 0, Amount, DateAdded
    FROM dbo.Invoices -- where clause?
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT InvoiceID, ReceiptID, Amount, DateAdded
    FROM dbo.Receipts -- where clause?
  ) AS y
),
z AS
(
  SELECT xrn = x.rn, x.InvoiceID, x.ReceiptID, x.Amount, x.DateAdded, 
    PlusMinus = CASE WHEN x.ReceiptID > 0 THEN -x.Amount ELSE x.Amount END
    FROM x LEFT OUTER JOIN x AS x2
    ON x.rn = x2.rn + 1
)
SELECT InvoiceID, ReceiptID, Balance = (
  SELECT SUM(COALESCE(PlusMinus, Amount)) 
  FROM z AS z2 
  WHERE z2.xrn <= z.xrn
), Amount, DateAdded
FROM z
ORDER BY DateAdded;
```

Cleanup:

```
DROP TABLE dbo.Invoices, dbo.Receipts;
```

Comment: Hi Aaron, this seems to work! Many thanks, bit of a complex query. I know you dont need to do this, but could you explain the WITH statement and how does the UNION help in this matter?

Comment: The WITH just defines a CTE (common table expression). It could easily be rewritten as nested subqueries, but I find this syntax gives better logical separation. The UNION helps because it treats all rows from both tables and when ordering only paying attention to the datetime value.

Comment: Many thanks Aaron. I have noticed that when I run this query in the SQL native manager it works, however, I've put this code into an ASP.NET page as a query (hardcoded to test) and exactly the same query errors and comes back with "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'." - Maybe this is something that I've done, but wanted to make sure it should work as it's standard SQL?

Comment: Are you sure you kept the leading `;`? If you did and .NET still gets confused by it, put it in a stored procedure and call the stored procedure. Not sure why you would ever want to dump this big SQL query and keep it in your application code. Who knows what other junk the interface is doing to the query.

Comment: Hi Aaron, I took it out - I put it back in now it says "Incorrect syntax near ';'." It doesn't like the semi-colon! In this instance I cant have a stored procedure, normally I would agree. Will this only work in an SP?

Comment: I can't really help unless I know what else the .NET code is doing to the query before it submits it. And again, I'll suggest you use stored procedures instead of submitting ad hoc queries from your application.

Comment: Hi Aaron, it's literally just querying the database. Nothing special, but it doesn't seem to like the ; or the WITH statement.

Answer (score -1):

you can make a view that select data from the 2 tables like if the DB is oracle :

```
CREATE VIEW INVOICE_RECPT_VIEW as 
select a.InvoiceID, b.RecieptID, b.Amount, b.Date_Added 
from invoices a, receipts b 
where a.InvoiceID = b.InvoiceID 
order by Date_Added
```

Comment: Tags say it's MS SQL Server - but your view should work anyway

Comment: I don't think this query captures the OP's requirements.